# SQL query in MS Access not retrieving values in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I created a method that retrieves the results from my MSAccess 2007 database but it's not returning any value. But when I copy the sql statement and paste it on the msaccess query design (SQL VIEW), I get the results that I expected. 
.

I uploaded the picture of its result.
[image]

It perfectly works when I retrieve all the values "SELECT * FROM tblItems". but when I add a condition, there are no result displaying in my C# App. 
Here's my code.

CLASS: DBConnection

```
public List<Item> getItems(string sql)
{
    List<Item> allItems = new List<Item>();
    Item thisItem = null;

    openConnection();

    command = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
    reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader.Read())
    {
        do
        {
            thisItem = new Item();

            thisItem.setItemID(Int32.Parse(reader["itemID"].ToString()));
            thisItem.setBarcode(reader["barcode"].ToString());
            thisItem.setBrandID(Int32.Parse(reader["brandID"].ToString()));
            thisItem.setCategoryID(Int32.Parse(reader["categoryID"].ToString()));
            thisItem.setCode(reader["code"].ToString());
            thisItem.setDescription(reader["description"].ToString());
            thisItem.setPrice(Double.Parse(reader["price"].ToString()));

            allItems.Add(thisItem);
        }
        while (reader.Read());
    }
    else
    {
        thisItem = null;
    }

    closeConnection();
    return allItems;
}
```

FORM CODE:

```
private void btnFilter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //MyFunctions func = new MyFunctions();
        DBConnection dbCon = new DBConnection();

        string brandID = cboBrand.SelectedValue.ToString().Equals("0") ? " > 0" : " = " + cboBrand.SelectedValue.ToString();
        string categoryID = cboCategory.SelectedValue.ToString().Equals("0") ? " > 0" : " = " + cboCategory.SelectedValue.ToString();

        string description = txtDescription.Text;
        string code = txtCode.Text;
        string barcode = txtBarcode.Text; 

        loadProducts(dbCon.getItems("SELECT * FROM tblItems WHERE [brandID] " + brandID + " AND [categoryID] " + categoryID + " AND [description] LIKE '*" + description + "' AND [code] LIKE '*" + code + "' AND [barcode] LIKE '*" + barcode + "'"));

    }




public void loadProducts(List<Item> allItems)
    {
        MyFunctions func = new MyFunctions();

        int i = 0;

        lvwItems.Items.Clear();
        foreach (Item thisItem in allItems)
        {
            lvwItems.Items.Add(thisItem.getItemID().ToString());
            lvwItems.Items[i].SubItems.Add(thisItem.getBarcode());
            lvwItems.Items[i].SubItems.Add(thisItem.getCategoryName());
            lvwItems.Items[i].SubItems.Add(thisItem.getBrandName());
            lvwItems.Items[i].SubItems.Add(thisItem.getCode());
            lvwItems.Items[i].SubItems.Add(thisItem.getDescription());
            lvwItems.Items[i].SubItems.Add(func.toCurrency(thisItem.getPrice()));

            i++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: your brandID, CategoryId are string it should be enclosed in ' (single quotes)..

Comment: I think the wildcard is different in C# expression. Try with % instead of * in your like condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT * FROM tblItems WHERE [brandID] " + brandID 
        + " AND [categoryID] " + categoryID +
         " AND [description] LIKE '*" + description 
       + "' AND [code] LIKE '*" + code 
       + "' AND [barcode] LIKE '*" + barcode + "'"
```

Comment: i remove the "=" sign in the brandID and categoryID statement because i have a condition. see the ASSIGNMENT STATEMENTS in the btnFilter_Click event. . it will retrieve the values of brandID and categoryID including the "=" sign or ">" sign.

Comment: @user4938771 ok then before executin this query assing it into a string variable and do a message box. Then check whether the query formed correctly with the values.

Comment: @user4938771 i think then the issue is assigning the "=" and ">" symbol..in the greater than symbol you are not concatenating selected category id and batch id..see my edited answer.

Comment: Solved It.. I Traced the SQL statement via immediated window, and it's correct.. the issue is, the wildcard being used in msaccess is different from C#. I replaced "*" with "%". Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.. :D I just replaced the wildcard "*" to "%".. Thanks.. especially to @Wery Nguyen.

Answer (score -1):

As to your screen shots, neither brandID nor categoryID are strings, but your SQL is incorrect. It should read like this:

```
loadProducts(dbCon.getItems("SELECT * FROM tblItems WHERE [brandID] = " + brandID + " AND [categoryID] = " + categoryID + " AND [description] LIKE '*" + description + "' AND [code] LIKE '*" + code + "' AND [barcode] LIKE '*" + barcode + "'"));
```

Comment: Sachu and Gustav:
.
i remove the "=" sign in the brandID and categoryID statement because i have a condition. see the ASSIGNMENT STATEMENTS in the btnFilter_Click event.
.
it will the retrieve the brandID and category including the "=" sign or ">" sign.